# SQL. Is it possible?

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle

select * from table1;

```
column1 |     column2    |    column3   |
a       |      2010      |       1      |
a       |      2011      |       2      |
a       |      2012      |       3      |
b       |      2010      |       4      |
b       |      2011      |       5      |
b       |      2012      |       6      |
c       |      2010      |       7      |
c       |      2011      |       8      |
c       |      2012      |       9      |
```

Is it possible to do something like this.

```
column1 |    2010    |    2011    |    2012    |
a       |     1      |      2     |      3     |
b       |     4      |      5     |      6     |
c       |     7      |      8     |      9     |
```

Comment: To answer the question in the topic: Yes, SQL is definitely possible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes

```
SELECT t.column1,
       (SELECT SUM(column3) FROM table1 
        WHERE column1 = t.column1 AND column2 = 2010) AS "2010",
       (SELECT SUM(column3) FROM table1 
        WHERE column1 = t.column1 AND column2 = 2011) AS "2011",
       (SELECT SUM(column3) FROM table1 
        WHERE column1 = t.column1 AND column2 = 2012) AS "2012"
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM table1
) t
ORDER BY t.column1
```

Note, I've added the `SUM()` aggregate function around `colum3` in case you may have duplicate values per `column1, column2`.

Depending on the database you're using, the following equivalent query might be a bit faster:

```
SELECT t.column1,
       (SELECT SUM(column3) FROM table1 
        WHERE column1 = t.column1 AND column2 = 2010) AS "2010",
       (SELECT SUM(column3) FROM table1 
        WHERE column1 = t.column1 AND column2 = 2011) AS "2011",
       (SELECT SUM(column3) FROM table1 
        WHERE column1 = t.column1 AND column2 = 2012) AS "2012"
FROM table1 t
GROUP BY t.column1
ORDER BY t.column1
```

Note that you can achieve the same in a more concise way, using the `PIVOT` clause (as others have suggested). In **Oracle 11g**, this would translate to:

```
SELECT column1, "2010", "2011", "2012"
FROM table1
PIVOT (SUM(column3) FOR column2 IN (2010, 2011, 2012))
```

In any case, I don't know any database that allows for a dynamic number of columns per table expression, without resorting to tricks involving XML or other means of dynamic SQL. Typically, those tricks aren't much faster than what I suggested here. This means, you'll always have to foresee, how many years you want to support as columns, and adapt your query accordingly

Comment: This isn't very scalable. What happens if records are `2013` next year?

Comment: The question was about this being possible, not scalable. Only Oracle and SQL Server ship with a `PIVOT` clause, which is more concise but essentially the same. Even then, you'd have to adapt the query for every additional year you want to support. Apart from that, I don't know any RDBMS that allows for a dynamic number of columns per  table expression...

Comment: You are right with PIVOT. If Scalability is not a problem for amka. Your solution is the better one. And DB independent.

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 6

Comment: I'm sorry, [`PIVOT` is only available in Oracle 11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28279/chapter1.htm#autoId192). You'll have to do without that keyword

Comment: i install and use oracle 11g r2 but not working http://i48.tinypic.com/30v0wu8.png

Answer (score 1):

try PIVOT in SQL sever

```
select column1  ,   [2010],[2011],[2012]
from your_table
PIVOT (MAX(column3) FOR column2 IN ([2010],[2011],[2012])) P
```

**Edit1**:

If your Column2 is dynamic, then try this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(column2) 
                    from your_table
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')



set @query = 'SELECT column1    , ' + @cols + ' from your_table
             pivot 
            (
                MAX(column3)
                for column2 in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
print(@query)
execute(@query)
```

Comment: Your solution is nice but DB specific. Without the DB info, it is hard to suggest a solution.